# Vue-Cli - How to load external files (out of root) in index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-cli

First of all, I have a folder structure like this (and can't modify):

> |- **base_shared**
>     |- controls
>       |- *.js files*
>     |-
> libs
>        |- *.js files*
>  |- **Project A**
> *(created with Vue-Cli)*
>  |- **Project B** *(created with Vue-Cli)*

Inside `base_shared` folder we store all of our files that need to be shared with all projects, it includes libs, UI controls, etc... Those are, in majority, `.js` files and don't have any kind of `export default` or similar, since they are simple .js. Those files are frequently modified and frequently there are new files added in `base_shared` that all projects can consume.

Folders `Project A/B` are Vue-Cli created projects, with own vue.config.js, routes and `.vue` components.
In each project we have a `public/index.html` file. Here we load big part of our libraries, .css and .js files. (not using `import()`, but using `<script src=...>` in the head)

> **My question is:**
>  How can I load files that are out of the <%= BASE_URL %> (in this case, files from `base_shared`) in the
> index.html of each project? All those files need to be globally accessible in all
> parts/views/components of the project during runtime.

I tried many things like:
`src="../base_shared/controls..."`
`src="<%= BASE_URL %>../base_shared/controls...`
but obviously it won't work since it is out of root/host scope (let's assume for now that host is http://localhost:8081/)
I'm also using in vue.config.js the webpack with a `resolve.alias` to as `'@base': path.resolve(__dirname, '../base_shared')`

I'm used to IIS servers where I can create a "Virtual Directory" to point to `base_shared` and then use it in my project like the folder was inside the project root (when it is not, it's virtual)

There's something like that in Vue/Node ? Can I configure a virtual path? Or I need to rethink the idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to set this into your vue.config.js?

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.resolve.alias
            .set('libs', path.resolve(__dirname, '../base_shared/'))
    }
}
```

Them you use an `import .... from ....` into your script block.

```
<script>
   import { packagename } from "packagefolder/package.js"
   import 'packagefolder/css/package.css'

   export default {
       ...       
   }
</script>
```

Comment: It worked in parts, but I'm marking as accepted since it helped me to find the way. I moved my imports to main.js and stored the necessary globals at `window`.